# Did anyone manage to use time manager with dates before 1900?

Tags: qgis, timemanager

a simple question. Did anyone manage to use time manager with dates before 1900? Other than the solution suggested by Anita in

[Is it possible to change the year range of time manager in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26720/is-it-possible-to-change-the-year-range-of-time-manager-in-qgis)

Answer (score 1):

Update: This has been fixed now: https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/issues/26

---

Old answer: 
There is no other solution. The bug is listed on the project homepage https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/issues/26

Comment: Txs. It appears that it doesn't work for dates after 2100 either. Excel doesn't manage date formats before 1900-01-01.